# Why might quasiquotation fail to pass a variable to `with()` inside a function?

Tags: r

**Issue**

I am trying to implement quasiquotation within a function to split a dataframe into parts according to levels in a factor. The function returns a `Error in levels(variable) : object 'Component' not found` error when run, where Component is a factor in the provided dataframe.

**Function**

```
split_by_factor <- function(x, variable){
  v <- quote(variable)
  el <- expr(with(x, levels(!!v)))
  l <- eval(el)
  result <- list()
  i <- 1
  for(level in l){
    e <- expr(with(x, x[!!v == level,]))
    result[i] <- eval(e)
    i <- i+1
  }
  return(result)
}
```

The function accepts a data frame as x and an unquoted factor variable within that data frame as variable. It is then supposed to return a list of data frames that have been separated by the levels in the provided factor

**Failed resolution**

When defining x and variable independently and running body of the function outside of the function call, everything works as intended. This lead me to believe it was an issue with operating within the function environment. I have tried switching `quote()` to `enquo()` and `expr()` to `enexpr()` as I read the `expr()` can misbehave within a function, but I get the similar error: `Error:`arg `must be a symbol`. Moreover, since `with()` sets the environment R should look for objects I am confused why this is behaving differently inside the function at all.

**Edit: Reproducible example**

```
sample_data <- data.frame(v1 = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE),
                          v2 = factor(x = sample(1:5, 10, replace = TRUE), 
                                      levels = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                                      labels = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")))

split_by_factor(sample_data, v2)
```

Error message received when running this example:

```
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in levels(variable) : object 'v2' not found
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: Sample data added to allow running of function and production of the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
v <- quote(variable)
```

will only store the symbol `variable`. It will not capture the symbol passed to your function. Which means when you call

```
el <- expr(with(x, levels(!!v)))
```

it will be running

```
el <- expr(with(x, levels(variable)))
```

at that point it will try to evaluate the argument you passed in and it will discover there is no such variable named `v2` in the global environment.

If you are just trying to pass in a column name to the `rlang` world, instead you should use `ensym` (though when I tested it, `enexpr` also worked just fine)

```
library(rlang)
split_by_factor <- function(x, variable){
  v <- ensym(variable)
  el <- expr(with(x, levels(!!v)))
  l <- eval(el)
  result <- list()
  i <- 1
  for(level in l){
    e <- expr(with(x, x[!!v == level,]))
    result[[i]] <- eval(e)
    i <- i+1
  }
  return(result)
}
```

This will now make sure you are running

```
el <- expr(with(x, levels(v2)))
```

Also, an unrelated error you have in your code is when you assign a value into a list, you want to use `[[]]` rather than `[]`. So you should have

```
result[[i]] <- eval(e)
```